What can I use to repair this chipped grout on my bathroom wall?
I’m not quite sure why this part of the grout on my bathroom wall chipped off, but could use some advice on the best way to repair without needing to regrout the entire wall.
Presumably I can just get a grout repair kit to fix this small area?


That actually looks like that grout was installed in two layers. The first layer was installed deeper into the grout space and the next layer added later on.  You'll want to get a grout saw and remove that existing grout and then get some unsanded grout and regrout the space smoothing it into the existing grout lines.

I assume that I can’t just add a layer of grout on top of that first layer (which still seems ok)?

@Eric  It will probably chip off like the previous layer.   You can try if but rough up the existing surface.

An oscillating saw blade might work better, depending on the gap between tiles.  The grout saws I've seen have usually been pretty fat.
